# Can this be cleaned up or condensed any?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I thought about using a `CASE` statement to clean up some of up, right now it runs in about 10 seconds.  Looking to condense that down as well as the redundant code calls.  Wondering if there is a better way than a `CASE`.

There are 3 separate blocks of code.  Each block does almost the exact same thing aside from assigning a color depending on how many days it has been in the queue.

Green Anything less than 1 day.
Yellow anything greater than 1 day but less than 3 days.
Red anything greater than 3 days.

```
select m.number, 'status1', 'Green', datediff(day, (select max(datechanged) from statushistory where accountid = m.number), getdate())
from master m with (nolock)
inner join customer c with (nolock) on m.customer = c.customer
where m.status = 'status1'
and datediff(day, (select max(sh.datechanged) from statushistory sh where accountid = m.number), getdate()) <= 1
and qlevel < 998
and (m.desk not like 'ATY%')
and (isnull(m.link,0) = 0 or m.linkdriver = 1)
and m.desk not in ('param1','param2','param3','param4','param5','param6','param7','param8','param9','param10','param11','param12')

select m.number, 'status1', 'Yellow', datediff(day, (select max(datechanged) from statushistory where accountid = m.number), getdate())
from master m with (nolock)
inner join customer c with (nolock) on m.customer = c.customer
where m.status = 'status1'
and datediff(day, (select max(sh.datechanged) from statushistory sh where accountid = m.number), getdate()) between 1 and 2
and qlevel < 998
and (m.desk not like 'ATY%')
and (isnull(m.link,0) = 0 or m.linkdriver = 1)
and m.desk not in ('param1','param2','param3','param4','param5','param6','param7','param8','param9','param10','param11','param12')

select m.number, 'status1', 'Red', datediff(day, (select max(datechanged) from statushistory where accountid = m.number), getdate())
from master m with (nolock)
inner join customer c with (nolock) on m.customer = c.customer
where m.status = 'status1'
and datediff(day, (select max(sh.datechanged) from statushistory sh where accountid = m.number), getdate()) >= 3
and qlevel < 998
and (m.desk not like 'ATY%')
and (isnull(m.link,0) = 0 or m.linkdriver = 1)
and m.desk not in ('param1','param2','param3','param4','param5','param6','param7','param8','param9','param10','param11','param12')
```

EDIT #1

```
select m.number, 'status1', 
CASE 
    WHEN datediff(day, (select max(sh.datechanged) from statushistory sh where accountid = m.number), getdate()) <= 1 THEN 'Green'
    WHEN datediff(day, (select max(sh.datechanged) from statushistory sh where accountid = m.number), getdate()) between 1 and 3 THEN 'Yellow'
    WHEN datediff(day, (select max(sh.datechanged) from statushistory sh where accountid = m.number), getdate()) > 3 THEN 'Red'
END
, datediff(day, (select max(datechanged) from statushistory where accountid = m.number), getdate())
from master m with (nolock)
inner join customer c with (nolock) on m.customer = c.customer
where m.status = 'status1'
--and datediff(day, (select max(sh.datechanged) from statushistory sh where accountid = m.number), getdate()) <= 1
and qlevel < 998
and (m.desk not like 'ATY%')
and (isnull(m.link,0) = 0 or m.linkdriver = 1)
and m.desk not in ('param','param','param','param','param','param','param','param','param','param','param','param')
```

Comment: I think a CASE statement is the way to go.

Comment: I would use a common table expression(CTE) see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Comment: @3dd I edited the original post with my CASE version.  Do you know how you might convert that into a CTE?  This results from this statement will need to be inserted into a table.

Comment: Note that `between` doesn't really mean it's "between" those two values. It is inclusive and translated to `>= value1 and <= value2` https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as (
    select 
        m.number, 
        m.status, 
        days = datediff(day, (select max(datechanged) from statushistory where accountid = m.number), getdate())
    from 
        master m with (nolock)
        inner join customer c with (nolock) on m.customer = c.customer
    where 
        m.status = 'status1'
        and d between 1 and 2
        and qlevel < 998
        and (m.desk not like 'ATY%')
        and (isnull(m.link,0) = 0 or m.linkdriver = 1)
        and m.desk not in ('param1','param2','param3','param4','param5','param6','param7','param8','param9','param10','param11','param12')

), colorThresholds as (
    select color = 'Green', minDays = null, maxDays = 1 union
    select 'Yellow', 2, 3 union
    select 'Red', 4, null
)

/* now apply the color thresholds */
select
    c.*,
    ct.color
from
    cte c
    /* outer join in case the thresholds don't cover all ranges */
    left outer join colorThresholds ct on
        (ct.minDays is null or c.days >= ct.minDays)
        and (ct.maxDays is null or c.days <= ct.maxDays)
```

Comment: Thanks dotjoe, I'm not too familiar with CTE's.  I actually had to comment out the and d between 1 and 2 out for it to work at all.  But even with that commented out it seems to show the exact results I am looking for.  do you know what advantages the CTE has over the CASE variant?

Comment: @JamesWilson cte's are basically an easy to (re)use subquery. One benfit is that the datediff function is only in one place. See how you had to copy it for each case statement? that makes it cumbersome to maintain.

Comment: @JamesWilson as far as the colorThresholds cte, that could be easily replaced by your CASE statement. CTE's are nice to use when you want to break down a query into smaller pieces. I like to use them when computed/calculated columns are going to be needed in other places like the where clause, joins, or part of other columns. Pretty much trying to avoid duplicated code.

Comment: Well thanks for the answer, it worked perfectly and runs fast.  thanks for the extra time spent explaining as well, I appreciate it.